# Trying to deploy war.file I am receiving an error

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

Trying to deploy war.file I am receiving an error.
I am using Wildfly 30 screen console to deploy my war.file but I am receiving an error:

```
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.\        "itcmedbr.com\""],
```

1626     "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
1627         "service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server."itcmedbr.com"./.UndertowDeploymentInfoServi        ce is missing [jboss.undertow.server.default-server."itcmedbr.com"]",
1628         "service jboss.deployment.unit."itcmedbr-1.0.war".undertow-deployment is missing [jboss.undert        ow.server.default-server."itcmedbr.com"]"
1629     ]

### The error say that itcmedbr.com is missing I don't know how and where to create this.
Thanks for all assistance.

I believe that this error is caused by due to lack configuration of a server in my wildfly server then I am trying to create one but I can't do it. This is my configuration:

```
"/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
```

................

```
         <server name="itcmedbr.com">
             <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
             <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="applicationSSC" enable-http2="true"/>
             <host name="itcmedbr.com" alias="www.itcmedbr.com">
                 <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                 <http-invoker http-authentication-factory="application-http-authentication"/>
             </host>
         </server>
         <servlet-container name="default">
             <jsp-config/>
             <websockets/>
         </servlet-container>
         <handlers>
             <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
         </handlers>
         <application-security-domains>
             <application-security-domain name="other" security-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
         </application-security-domains>
     </subsystem>
```

............."

Comment: I forgot to say the "itcmedbr.com" is my domain.

Comment: Please share more information. What applications are installed? How does the configuration look like? Do you have any idea why Wildfly might believe your domain is a required service?

Comment: Thank you queeg, I had a problem in my Eclipse IDE then I was using my war file from .m2 directory now after reinstall my Eclipse and generate my war file project I am receiving the error "java.io.IOException: No such file or directory" in the Wildfly console deplyments.
Environment:
. Linux Centos 8
. Java
. Mysql
. Wildfly 30
. Nginx

Comment: After to configure a server on standalone.xml the problem of deployments was solved.